# Bad subforcings of nice forcing notions

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Let $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be two forcing notions. Recall that we say $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subforcing of $\mathbb{P}$ if there exists a regular embedding $\mathbb{Q} \to \text{r.o.}(\mathbb{P}).$

**Question.** Let $\mathbb{P} \in \{Add(\omega, \kappa), Col(\omega_1, \kappa) \}.$

(1) Is there a subforcing of $\mathbb{P}$ which is not Proper?

(2) Is there a subforcing of $\mathbb{P}$ which is not semi-Proper?

**Remark.** In [Subalgebras of Cohen algebras need not be Cohen](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9610227), Koppelberg and Shelah show that there is a subalgebra of Cohen forcing which is not Cohen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  A subforcing of a c.c.c. forcing is c.c.c.  A subforcing of a countably closed forcing is countably-strategically-closed, which implies proper.  (This is easy to see via countable elementary submodels.  Use the strategy to construct a generic condition.)

Furthermore, every subforcing of a proper forcing is proper.  Properness is equivalent to preserving stationary subsets of $[\kappa]^\omega$ for all $\kappa$.  The stationarity of $X \subseteq [ \kappa ]^\omega$ cannot be restored once killed, since killing it is just adding some $f : [\kappa]^{<\omega} \to \kappa$ such that no $x \in X$ is closed under $f$.  (See Abraham's chapter of the Handbook.)

Comment: Dear Monroe, thanks a lot; I will use this result to give an answer to the question "http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134101/existence-of-a-regular-subposet-which-collapses-everything-except-the-top-cardin"